# Collision logic brick not detecting collision in BGE

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, collision

I am making a game in the BGE and I don't want my character going off the platform. I have is set to quit the game when that happens (I am going to change that later), and the walls let him pass right through. How can I prevent that?

[image: Passing right through]

I want him to stop at the walls. Here is the logic:

[image: Logic bricks]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your character have "Static" physics?
If yes,just change character's physics to "Dynamic"[image: here]

Comment: yes. that worked. I don't know much about blender. Thanks